# How to find number of nodes in ethereum using web3?

Tags: web3js

Is there a way to find the number of nodes in the ethereum network using the **web3** javascript console?

There is a command to find the **number of peers**, but couldn't find a query to get the total **number of nodes** in the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decentralized nature of the Ethereum network makes it hard to know how many nodes are connected at a given moment, since there's no central registry where every node should connect. Web3.js doesn't have a method that returns such query.

Block explorer like [ethernodes.org](https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1) approximate that number querying seval known nodes. You can try asking them if they provide a public api.

Answer (score 0):

To have info about the no of peers connected at any moment try admin.peers.

Comment: Question is about `the total number of nodes`, not peers.